# Writing complex stored procedures in H2 database

Tags: database, stored-procedures, h2

I have an oracle stored procedure in which first of all I am opening a cursor with complex select query using "cases" and later iterating the cursor and then inserting or updating the records based on some condition. I want this to be written in H2 database.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to rewrite your stored procedure in Java, according to the manual:

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions

Within that Java stored procedure, you can create new statements (i.e. cursors) and do whatever you can do with Java